# How do you print a void function call side by side in C

Tags: c, function, formatting, multiple-columns, void

I am trying to print two void function calls in a single line, instead of having to print it on a new line.
So here is what it's printing right now:

```
void function 1 returns:
mode: 1
mode: 2
mode: 3
...
void function 2 returns:
mode: 1
mode: 2
mode: 3
...
```

What I want it to output ss:

```
function 1                      function 2
mode: 1                         mode: 1
mode: 2                         mode: 2
mode: 3                         mode: 3
```

Right now, basically I just have my code like this:

```
   displayMode(x.data, n);             
   displayMode(y.data, n);
```

displayMode finds modes from an array and returns the frequency of that number and the value, and multiple values if there's more than one mode.

How do you get it to print side by side? I tried printf, which did not work. I am not sure if there is a way to do this. I tried searching with Google; however, I am not sure what term to use for the search.

Comment: You will have to make major changes to the functions so that they can cooperate on the printing. I’d probably start with a single function that’s passed both `x.data` and `y.data`, and then rework the insides to print cooperatively

Comment: If rewriting as suggested isn’t feasible, revise the function to print to a string, and then call the function with two different strings and finally post-process the strings so the data is formatted correctly.

Comment: I must be tired, how did I not think of that! thank you